# ¿Cómo estucturar las bases de datos en un CRM?

Tags: mysql, pdo

En un CRM para guardar los registros he utilizado 2 tablas: una de datos actuales modificados por los usuarios (que se actualiza con un UPDATE) y otra de historial de las modificaciones (que incluye una nueva fila con un INSERT) al guardad las modifica .

De este modo al guardar la forma con diferentes inputs se ejecuta el código que, primero, hace un UPDATE en tabla de datos actuales y segundo, se hace un INSERT en la tabla de historial de modificaciones.

Acorde con las mejores prácticas de PDO + MySQL, ¿cómo debería estructurar las tablas? Lo pregunto porque estoy pensando deshacerme de la tabla de situaciones actuales y solamente utilizar la de historial. Cogería los datos para representar los registros actuales para los usuarios de la tabla de historial con 'ORDER BY fecha_registro LIMIT 1'.

Comment: En mi opinión es mala idea que uses una tabla con datos históricos como base para las operaciones de tu sistema, pueden surgir muchos problemas; uno simple: ¿cómo controlar cuando tu servidor tenga una fecha incorrecta y no accedas a los datos más recientes? Se me ocurren otros inconvenientes también: tamaño de la tabla, indexado, migraciones, explotación de datos (por ejemplo para reportes), etc. Te recomiendo que leas sobre *normalización de bases de datos* para darte ideas sobre la estructuración de tus tablas.

Comment: Gracias por tú cometario @Fer me podrías responder a la pregunta ampliando tu comentario como respuesta? Me interesa mucho la parte sobre normalización que comentas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te comenté antes, una buena idea es aplicar normalización a tu base de datos. Al normalizar una base de datos se aplican ciertas reglas a la estructura de tus tablas y las relaciones entre ellas para reducir *la redundancia de datos* y *mejorar su integridad*: una tabla completamente normalizada estaría protegida de este tipo de problemas.

La [normalización](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos) tiene varias fases de aplicación (llamadas "formas normales"), donde la tercera forma normal genera una estructura totalmente normalizada. Sin embargo, en la práctica no se suele normalizar completamente una estructura de datos porque puede generar otros problemas. Como ejemplo, en la primera forma normal debe existir un identificador único de nuestros registros y, además, debe eliminarse cualquier campo no-atómico convirtiéndolo a distintos campos atómicos (o sea que guardan un elemento de datos único); ilustrando lo anterior podríamos tener la siguiente *pseudo-tabla* de clientes:

```
Nombre       cadena,
Domicilio    cadena,
Telefono     cadena,
FechaAlta    fecha
```

para convertir en primera forma normal, debemos agregar una *llave primaria* y eliminar los campos atómicos; `Nombre` y `Domicilio` parecen ser dos opciones para esto:

```
IDCliente    entero <llave>,
Nombre       cadena,
Apellido1    cadena,
Apellido2    cadena,
Calle        cadena,
Numero       cadena,
CodigoPostal entero,
Ciudad       cadena,
Pais         cadena,
Telefono     cadena,
FechaAlta    fecha
```

sin embargo, puede ser una carga extra para un sistema el tener que gestionar todos los campos generados al normalizar de manera estricta una estructura. Lo recomendable sería estudiar las distintas reglas de normalización y aplicarlas de manera práctica a nuestras tablas.

Volviendo a tu problema y después de hablar brevemente sobre normalización, podemos determinar que el mantener una única tabla con los registros usados para operación del sistema además del histórico de los mismos datos suena a **redundancia de datos**: uno de los problemas que intenta eliminar la normalización.

Podemos visualizar dos problemas a resolver por el sistema:

1. La operación "normal" (*operaciones transaccionales*), donde se generan y manipulan los datos propios de la aplicación; por ejemplo: registros de clientes, proveedores, facturas, etc. Esto se conoce como OLTP (On-Line Transaction Processing / Procesamiento de Transacciones en Línea).
2. La explotación de datos "históricos" generados durante la operación; es decir, tareas como generación de informes, auditoría de datos, estadísticas para toma de decisiones, etc. Esto se conoce como OLAP (On-Line Analytical Processing / Procesamiento Analítico en Línea).

Los conceptos indicados (OLTP / OLAP) normalmente son aplicados e implementados por sistemas completamente separados: incluso es común que el *software* de base de datos se configure de manera distinta según la función que desempeñará. Sin embargo, lo anterior no significa que puedan implementarse algunas de estas ideas para diseñar un sistema "relativamente pequeño".

Lo ideal es mantener estructuras o tablas normalizadas (hasta donde sea posible) para cubrir la operación de nuestra aplicación (punto 1) y generar copias de dichos datos en nuevas tablas "transformadas" que tengan la única función de servir como fuente para la explotación de datos (punto 2). Curiosamente, lo recomendable para la transformación de dichas copias es aplicar [denormalización](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalizaci%C3%B3n_(base_de_datos)) (o sea añadir redundancia de datos), para mejorar el rendimiento de tales operaciones. Cada estructura estaría diseñada para cubrir las necesidades de cada tarea.

Y también es importante mantener el sentido común al diseñar las estructuras: tal vez sea importante mantener un histórico de nuestro catálogo de clientes (*¿qué campos en los registros modificados han cambiado a través del tiempo y quién ha aplicado dichos cambios?*), pero, el gestionar copias similares para otro catálogo (por ejemplo de usuarios del sistema) no sea tan importante; probablemente con mantener una bitácora genérica de cambios sea suficiente, sin registrar cada campo cambiado.

Moviéndonos hacia ideas más prácticas, podrías implementar la copia de datos mediante el uso de [*triggers*](http://cassianinet.blogspot.mx/2011/07/triggers-disparadores-en-mysql.html) (disparadores): de esta manera relegarías la generación de esos datos a la misma base de datos en vez de hacer tales operaciones desde tu propia aplicación.

En resumen, el diseño de las estructuras de datos para una aplicación es una tarea compleja y aquí solamente estoy tocando una pequeña parte del mismo; sin embargo, espero que lo expuesto aquí te sirva para darte ideas sobre cómo proceder en la implementación de tu sistema.

Comment: O sea, lo mejor para mi caso será dejar las dos tablas y aplicar un trigger en vez de llevar a cabo un código que ejecutra INSERT y UPDATE al mismo tiempo.

Comment: De esa manera evitas sobrecargar tu aplicación con código que podría generar alguna excepción y no hacer lo requerido: le dejas esa responsabilidad a la misma base de datos. Y puedes implementar un trigger para cada operación (insert o update) que haga lo propio para cada opción.